# repeat each column of a given matrix for a numbr of times in matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose the input matrix is:

```
a=[1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9];
```

the expect output matrix would be:

```
[1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3 
 4  4  4  5  5  5  6  6  6
 7  7  7  8  8  8  9  9  9]
```

Is there a neat matlab function to do this? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: This question surely has a duplicate somewhere; but I suggest looking at the `kron` function...Hint: use `ones(x,y)` as well. I'll let you figure out what `x` and `y` need to be :)

Comment: Thanks for introducing 'kron' function to me, Benoit. This is whart I was thinking.  'a = [1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9];  b=[1;1;1]; c=kron(b,a); reshape(c, [3,9])'. Well, it has more than one functions here though.

Comment: You're welcome! Use `b = kron(a,ones(1,3))`. Have fun!